# A heavy simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-\frac{\sum _{i=1}^{m-1} 2^{i-1} \left(\binom{m}{i-1}-3^{m-i}\right)}{m-1}==2^{m-1}$$
Is there a way to show that this equation makes a  true statement?

I am somehow stuck here

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: @mvw this is already part of an induction but if you think it will get me any further then I'll try! So just switch m with m+1 and substitute $2^{m-1}$ as soon as possible to show that it's equal to $2^m$, right?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Try to use the binomial theorem (with $x=2$)

$$(1+x)^m = \sum_{i=0}^m {m\choose i} x^i$$

and the sum of a geometric series (with $x=\frac{2}{3}$)

$$\sum_{i=0}^m x^i = \frac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}$$